# Multipart form-data upload file - Formulario HTML PHP

Tags: php, html, upload, multipart

**Dudas:**

**1)** ¿Se puede meter un formulario dentro de otro formulario? Me explico. Tengo un formulario llamado "anadir" donde quiero agregar otro formulario llamado "subir_archivos" debido a que quiero que al pulsar "Guardar", previamente seleccionando las imágenes deseadas, se envién los datos del formulario "añadir".

**2)** Sólo me deja seleccionar una imagen, ¿se pueden elegir varias para subirlas de una vez? ¿Se podrían subir varias imágenes?

**Código:**

```
<?php
    require_once "Clases/BD.php";
    require_once "Clases/Cabanas.php";
    require_once "conexion.php";

    //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
    session_start();
    //Si existe la sesión "administrador"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
        $administrador = $_SESSION['administrador'];
    }

    //Si pulsamos el botón "Guardar"... 
    //Realizamos el "INSERT" antes que el "SELECT" para que se actualice la tabla correctamente.
    if(isset($_POST["guardar"])){
        $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
        $capacidad = $_POST["capacidad"];
        $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
        $precio = $_POST["precio"];
        //Llamamos al método "anadirCabana" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
        BD::anadirCabana($nombre, $capacidad, $descripcion, $precio);
    }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Panel del administrador</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sesion_administrador">
            <?php 
            if(isset($_SESSION['administrador'])){
                echo "Bienvenido ".$administrador."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='salir_administrador.php?salir=1'>Salir</a>"; //GET
                //_REQUEST = $_POST o $_GET
                if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
                    unset($_SESSION["administrador"]);
                    header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_administrador.php");
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="tabla_datos_cabana" id="tabla_datos_cabana" method="POST">
            <div id="mostrar_cabanas">
            <br/><br/><br/>
                <table class="table table-striped" name="tabla" width="600" border="2" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: 10pt">
                    <center>
                        <tr>
                            <thead style="background-color:#A9F5A9">
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>ID Cabaña</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"250\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Nombre</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Modificar</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Eliminar</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                            </thead>
                        </tr>   
                        <?php
                        $datos = BD::obtenerCabanas();
                        foreach($datos as $cabana){
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>".$cabana->getIdcabana()."</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"250\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>".$cabana->getNombre()."</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><font face=\"verdana\"><font size='2'><center>"?> 
                                    <a href="modificar.php?idcabana=<?=$cabana->getIdcabana();?>">
                                        <img src="imagenes/modificar.png" height='24' width='26' onmouseover="this.src='imagenes/modificar_in.png';" onmouseout="this.src='imagenes/modificar.png';">
                                    </a> <?php "</center></font></font></td>";
                                echo "<td width=\"150\"><center><input type='checkbox' name='marcados[]' id='marcados[]' value=".$cabana->getIdcabana()."></center>";
                         echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </center>
                </table>

                <!-- Botón NUEVA cabaña -->
                <div class="boton_anadir" class="table-responsive" align="left">
                    <font face="verdana">
                        <b><input type="button" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="nueva_cabana" id="nueva_cabana" value="Añadir cabaña"></b>
                    </font><br/>
                </div>

                <!-- Botón ELIMINAR cabaña/s -->
                <div class="boton_eliminar" class="table-responsive" align="left">
                    <font face="verdana">
                        <b><input type="submit" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="eliminar_cabanas" id="eliminar_cabanas" onclick="return confirm('¿Deseas realmente eliminar estas cabañas?');" value="Eliminar cabañas"></b>
                    </font><br/>
                </div>

                <?php
                //Si pulsamos el botón "Eliminar cabañas"...
                if(isset($_POST['eliminar_cabanas'])){
                    if(empty($_POST['marcados'])){
                        echo "<h4><center>No se ha seleccionado ninguna cabaña.</center></h4>";
                    }else{
                        foreach($_POST['marcados'] as $valor){
                            //Nos conectamos a la base de datos.
                            $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "osmarrural");
                            //Realizamos la consulta.
                            $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana='%d'", $valor);
                            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
                            /*
                            $mysqli = new mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "osmarrural");
                            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana = ?");
                            $stmt->bind_param('i', $valor);
                            $stmt->execute(); 
                            $stmt->close();
                            */
                        }
                        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; URL=panel_administrador.php\">";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </form>

        <br/><br/><br/>
        <!-- Añadir una cabaña -->
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="anadir" id="anadir" method="POST" onsubmit="return validar_formulario_cabana();">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
                <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" />
            <br/><br/>
            <label for="capacidad">Capacidad: </label>
                <?php
                echo "<select name='capacidad'>";
                for($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
                    if($i==1){
                        echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
                    }
                }
                echo "</select>";
                ?>
            <br/><br/>
            <label for="descripcion">Descripción: </label>
                <input type="text" id="descripcion" name="descripcion">
            <br/><br/>
            <label for="precio">Precio: </label>
                <input type="text" id="precio" name="precio">
            <br/><br/>

            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" id="guardar" name="guardar"/>
            <input type="reset" value="Resetear" id="resetear" name="resetear"/>
        </form>
        <!-- ¿Es necesario añadir otro "formulario" para el botón o se puede realizar mediante el botón "Guardar" -->
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="subir_archivos" method="POST">
            <input name="uploadedfile" type="file"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Subir archivos"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: En cuanto a la primera pregunta. Lo que dices es que los formularios se envien a 2 partes diferentes al mismo tiempo al dar clic submit?

Comment: Que al mismo tiempo, al pulsar en "Guardar" perteneciente al primer formulario, se envién también los archivos elegidos en el buscador de ficheros. Que se realice TODO al mismo tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) ¿Se puede meter un formulario dentro de otro formulario? Me
>   explico. Tengo un formulario llamado "anadir" donde quiero agregar
>   otro formulario llamado "subir_archivos" debido a que quiero que al
>   pulsar "Guardar", previamente seleccionando las imágenes deseadas, se
>   envién los datos del formulario "añadir".

De poder se puede. Lo que no puedes hacer es enviar los datos de ambos formulario al mismo tiempo haciendo un submit debido a que un submit redirecciona la pagina y no puedes redireccionar una pagina 2 veces al mismo tiempo.

Para poder enviar ambos datos juntos tienen que estar en el mismo formulario o enviarlos por separado utilizando ajax.

> 2) Sólo me deja seleccionar una imagen, ¿se pueden elegir varias para
>   subirlas de una vez? ¿Se podrían subir varias imágenes?

Utiliza el atributo atributo `multiple` en el `input[type=file]`:

```
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" multiple="multiple"/>
```

Comment: ¿Existe la opción de mostrar en miniatura los elementos seleccionados o escribir los nombres de los ficheros elegidos? En lugar del texto: "X archivos".

Comment: No puedes cambiar el texto de un input file. Para eso tendras que crear tu propio control o utilizar uno ya hecho llamado [Bootstrap FileStyle](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/).

Comment: ¿Entonces se podría enviar tanto el formulario (nombre, descripción, capacidad, precio) como también las imágenes al pulsar el botón "Guardar" en el mismo formulario?